# Is it possible to use IonModal in a child page of a IonNav?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I have a SPA using the Ionic 7 Framework.  I'm using the templated starter project with menu/navigation icons at the bottom of the screen; think Reddit, Facebook, Twitter iOS app screen layout.
On some of the pages, I have a modal popup that is working fine to open and close using the links or pressing the Escape key.
The way the app works though is that sometimes a "page" is a standalone page navigated to directly from the navigation icons at the bottom of the screen, and sometimes it's navigated to through a list of items (IonList) contained as a child of a IonNav.  When it's standalone, the modal close/confirm links work, but when it's a child of the IonNav, the links don't work.

The PostsList component has a modal in it and it works in this case.  Opens, closes with the cancel & confirm links, as well as the Escape key.

```
<IonRouterOutlet id="main">
    <Route exact path="/postslist">
        <PostsList />
    </Route>
</IonRouterOutlet>
```

When it is wrapped in the IonNav component, the page displays fine, the modal shows with no code changes, but the cancel & confirm links no longer work.  Escape key works to cancel it.

```
<IonRouterOutlet id="main">
    <Route exact path="/postslist">
        <IonNav root={() => <PostsList />} swipeGesture={true}></IonNav>
    </Route>
</IonRouterOutlet>
```

The event handlers don't even fire.  I have had console.log lines in both close events, and in the first example they work, but in the second they don't.

I've copied code directly from the docs and double checked variable names and narrowed it down to the IonNav causing the issue.
I also switched out the PostsList component for another that has a modal in it, and it now behaves the same.

I also tried removing the SwipeGestures prop and it behaved the same.

Is there something I'm missing, or is it just impossible to do this using the built-in triggers?

In the PostList component (and similar in the substituted component), this is the IonFab button to open the modal, and then the IonModal code.  Both are very simple examples.

```
<IonFab slot="fixed" vertical="bottom" horizontal="end">
    <IonFabButton id="new-post-modal">
        <IonIcon icon={add} onClick={() => { }}></IonIcon>
    </IonFabButton>
</IonFab>
<IonModal ref={modalNewPost} trigger="new-post-modal" onWillDismiss={(ev) => onWillDismiss(ev)}>
    <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
            <IonButtons slot="start">
                <IonButton onClick={() => modalNewPost.current?.dismiss()}>Cancel</IonButton>
            </IonButtons>
            <IonTitle>Add New Post !!!!</IonTitle>
            <IonButtons slot="end">
                <IonButton strong={true} onClick={confirm}>
                    Confirm
                </IonButton>
            </IonButtons>
        </IonToolbar>
    </IonHeader>
    <IonContent className="ion-padding">
        <h1>New Post</h1>
        <p>This is the new post page.</p>
    </IonContent>
</IonModal>
```